# What do you call a sung syllable without any meaning?

Tags: word-request

Example of this are:

> "Nanana na na nana... I am happy, nana na na"
>
> "Lala la la la la. We are the gnomes. lala la la la"

Is there a word for this? I thought it was a onomatopoeia, but I don't think they are, or at least they belong to a different subclass.

Comment: nonsense syllables, like in jazz scatting

Comment: How technical do you want the answer.  There seems to be a technical linguist term (that non-specialists won't understand) Several different terms in different genre's of music but no general common word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) they are called **wordless** or **nonsense** syllables.